# $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $(Y|X =x) \sim \mathcal B(n,x)$. Find the p.d.f of $Y$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Good afternoon, I'm trying to find the p.d.f of $Y$ in the following exercise:

> [image]

**My attempt:**

It follows from $(Y|X =x) \sim \mathcal B(n,x)$ that $f_{Y|X =x} (k) = {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$. Then $$f_Y (k) = \sum_{x \in [0,1]} f_{Y|X =x} (k) \cdot f_X(x) = \int_0^1 {n \choose k}x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I'm stuck at computing this integral.

Could you please shed me some light on computing it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Consider the pdf of Beta distribution. Also there is a binomial coefficient in the pmf of Binomial distribution.

Comment: And why is there a sum in the first step that converts to an integral in the next step?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, my teacher said that when the sum over uncountably many $x$'s, we use integral ;(

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake! @BGM

Comment: @Akira It is still clear if you simply use the integral to start with. As for the integral, there is nothing to compute. It is a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom! I'm just exposed to the probability theory :(

Comment: Why are so unhappy?

Comment: @Akira You can answer your own question if you have solved it.